# RealmSwift: Shorten build compilation time

Tags: ios, realm

I just included the RealmSwift pod into my Podfile:

```
pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 1.0.2'
```

Really cool pod, but it does add another 4 minutes of build time to my CI server (bitrise.io).

Is there a way to configure RealmSwift pod so that it doesn't compile certain modules that I don't need? It feels a bit heavy - and in this way it's NOT living up to its "lightweight" competitive advantage against Core Data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using CocoaPods means you're choosing to build libraries from source. If the time it takes to build a library from source is troublesome for you, you could consider using a dependency manager that can use prebuilt binaries, such as Carthage, or [use Realm's prebuilt binaries directly](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#installation-swift-22).

Comment: This action alone literally saved me 5 min of build time on the server. Awesome!